# How to evaluate if a match has been found

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection, orb

Ok, so what I want to know is how do I evaluate if I found a match or not.

Say we have two descriptors, they were compute by using the ORB algorithm. Then I use the BFMatcher like so:

```
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING, false);
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
std::vector<DMatch> matches, good_matches;
...
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

What does the matches vector tell me? When did I find a match?

Comment: matches should be a vector of indices, telling which descriptors match best. descriptors1 is a SET of descriptors, descriptors2 is another set. Depending on your input (e.g. descriptors1 are the keypoints' descriptors of an object you want to detect), you can accept a matching if enough matches were found, their quality is ok (matches[i].distance < thres) and/or maybe all the matches can be described with a single homography.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html for checking the feature's quality. But I still do not understand the relation between descriptors and matches. For example the descriptor has a size of lets say 32. The matches vector has a size of 2. `good_matches` also has a size of 2. Is this a match or not? Because the size reduction from 32 to 2 seems too drastic. But the matches which were found seem to be good enough.

Comment: might depend on your appplication. e.g. for homography calculation you need more matches and you want to have some additional matches to verify the calculated homography.
And again, the size of a `single descriptor` is something different to the size of the `descriptors vector`, which holds ALL descriptors of all keypoints.
Did you try the bruteMatcher? I have no experience with FLANN so no idea how that one behaves.

Comment: Well, I am already using the bruteMatcher = BFMatcher (I think?). The descriptors1/2 are defined like this `Mat descriptors1, descriptors1;`. I am not sure how good it could get you know. If the size of them is 32 then would I be able to get (in the best conditions) 32 matches or will it ALWAYS be less? Thanks!

Comment: sure there can be 100% matches. In my older projects I had a panorama stitching software and extracted 600-1000 SURF features in each image. My selfprogrammed bruteforce matcher matched about 60-80% of the features in most frames.
But I'm not so sure what criteria the OpenCV matcher use to classify as `not matched`, maybe someone else knows that.

Comment: what kind of features do you extract/describe?
`One of NORM_L1, NORM_L2, NORM_HAMMING, NORM_HAMMING2. L1 and L2 norms are preferable choices for SIFT and SURF descriptors, NORM_HAMMING should be used with ORB, BRISK and BRIEF`
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html

Comment: Yea, I am using ORB. I think I have to experiment a bit more with it.